# Is there a way to use multiple auth_request directives in nginx?

Tags: authentication, nginx, request

I would like to use multiple `auth_request` directives in order to try authentication with multiple servers - i.e. if the first auth server returns `403`, try the second auth server. I tried a straightforward approach like this:

```
location /api {
    satisfy any;
    auth_request    /auth-1/;
    auth_request    /auth-2/;
    proxy_pass http://api_impl;
}

location /auth-1/ {
    internal;
    proxy_pass              http://auth_server_1;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}

location /auth-2/ {
    internal;
    proxy_pass              http://auth_server_2;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

But nginx wouldn't parse the config file. I received the response

```
nginx: [emerg] "auth_request" directive is duplicate
```

Is there a way to achive such functionality in nginx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution after finding this question in google looking for the same things:

- Set an upstream server that will pass to loopback nginx servers
- Make those upstream servers do what your /auth-1 and /auth-2 endpoints were doing, except they return **503** on authentication error (except the last in the chain that still returns 401 to signal to nginx that there are no more servers to try)
- Tell nginx on `/auth` to just use this upstream, so it will try all authentication "servers" sequentially (thanks to the 503 return codes) until one of them succeeds OR the last one returns 401.

```
upstream auth {
    server 127.0.2.1:8000 max_fails=0;
    server 127.0.2.1:8001 max_fails=0;
    server 127.0.2.1:8002 max_fails=0;
}

# Method 1
server {
    listen 127.0.2.1:8000;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://auth_server_1; # Returns **503** on failure
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
}

# Method 2
server {
    listen 127.0.2.1:8001;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://auth_server_2; # Returns **503** on failure
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
}

# Method 3
server {
    listen 127.0.2.1:8002;

    location / {
        proxy_pass              http://auth_server_3; # Returns **401** on failure
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    # ...
    location /api {
        auth_request    /auth;
        proxy_pass http://api_impl;
    }

    location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://auth/;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URL $request_uri;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_503;
    }
    # ...
}
```

Comment: What's the difference b/w methods 1,2 and 3, I did the same config. but it's load-balancing the upstream servers. not sequentially executing it? can you suggests

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but found a different solution that may be acceptable in certain scenarios.  It essentially creates a double-proxy layer which has a significant performance penalty.  The first proxy layer is for "authentication" and the second proxy layer is for "authorization".

The following configuration is untested and is to convey the concept rather than a working example.

```
### What I wanted

location /protected_path {
    auth_request /authenticate; # Login to IDP
    auth_request /authorize;    # Apply Role/Group based authorization
    # Final routing logic
}

### My solution

server {
    listen 443;
    location /protected_path {
        auth_request /authenticate;
        auth_request_set $idp-data $arbitrary_data_from_idp_server;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Arbitrary-Header $idp-data;
    }
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8000;
    location /protected_path {
        auth_request /authorize;
        # Final routing logic
    }
}
```