# NGINX check multiple endpoints with auth_request

Tags: nginx

We would like NGINX to check 3 different endpoints and allow a request through if *any* of the endpoints return 200. How can we use `auth_request` possibly with `upstream` and/or `proxy_next_upstream http_403` to achieve this?

Background: we want to allow sessions (cookie) through and need to check 3 possible application servers where the session could be valid. Only if all three respond negatively should the authentication fail.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822565/is-there-a-way-to-use-multiple-auth-request-directives-in-nginx.